# if / elsif to case statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, case-statement

I have a class which has private methods within it. I use a public method to call each of the private methods and check if a bingo card has bingo or not. Currently, it is written as such:

```
def check_card
    if check_horizontal == true
      bingo = "BINGO!"
    elsif check_vertical == true
      bingo = "BINGO!"
    elsif check_diagonal_right_to_left == true
      bingo = "BINGO!"
    elsif check_diagonal_left_to_right == true
      bingo = "BINGO!"
    else
      bingo = "Sorry, no Bingo."
    end
    puts "The result of your card is: #{bingo}"
  end
```

This currently works and passes my tests, however, I would like to be able to write the if/elsif statement as a case statement and have tried this:

```
def check_card
  bingo = case @bingo_card
          when check_horizontal then "BINGO!"
          when check_vertical then "BINGO!"
          when check_diagonal_right_to_left then "BINGO!"
          when check_diagonal_left_to_right then "BINGO!"
          else "Sorry, no bingo!"
          end
  puts "The result of your card is: #{bingo}"
end
```

but it returns all of the tests as `"Sorry, no bingo!"`

Am I missing something with regard to case statement syntax? Below is the entire class:

```
class BingoScorer
  attr_reader :bingo_card
  def initialize(bingo_card=nil)
    @bingo_card = bingo_card
  end
  def add_card(card)
    @bingo_card = card
  end
  def check_card
    if check_horizontal == true
      bingo = "BINGO!"
    elsif check_vertical == true
      bingo = "BINGO!"
    elsif check_diagonal_right_to_left == true
      bingo = "BINGO!"
    elsif check_diagonal_left_to_right == true
      bingo = "BINGO!"
    else
      bingo = "Sorry, no Bingo."
    end
    puts "The result of your card is: #{bingo}"
  end
  private
  def check_horizontal
    i = 0
    x_index_array = []
    @bingo_card.length.times do
      if @bingo_card[i].join == "xxxxx"
        x_index_array << @bingo_card[i]
      end
      i += 1
    end
    x_index_array.uniq.length == 1 ? true : false
  end
  def check_vertical
    i = 0
    x_index_array = []
    @bingo_card.length.times do
      x_index_array << @bingo_card[i].index('x')
      i += 1
    end
    x_index_array.uniq.length == 1 ? true : false
  end
  def check_diagonal_right_to_left
    i = 0
    x_index_array = []
    @bingo_card.length.times do
      x_index_array << @bingo_card[i][i]
      i += 1
    end
    x_index_array.uniq.length == 1 ? true : false
  end
  def check_diagonal_left_to_right
    idx1 = 0
    idx2 = 4
    x_index_array = []
    @bingo_card.length.times do
      x_index_array << @bingo_card[idx1][idx2]
      idx1 += 1
      idx2 -= 1
    end
    x_index_array.uniq.length == 1 ? true : false
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: As a matter of coding style, use whitespace between your method definitions. Whitespace doesn't slow the program and it makes it a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing `@bingo_card` to the value of `check_horizontal` et al. Instead, remove the `@bingo_card` part:

```
def check_card
  bingo = case # nothing here #
          when check_horizontal then "BINGO!"
          when check_vertical then "BINGO!"
          when check_diagonal_right_to_left then "BINGO!"
          when check_diagonal_left_to_right then "BINGO!"
          else "Sorry, no bingo!"
          end
  puts "The result of your card is: #{bingo}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Nate. This was helpful and it seems awfully obvious now.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the case syntax, which [@NateSymer covers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778366/14660), your code violates the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by repeating the same result for different cases.  You'd be better off using the logical OR operator, `||`

```
def check_card
    if check_horizontal || check_vertical ||
       check_diagonal_right_to_left || check_diagonal_left_to_right
      bingo = "BINGO!"
    else
      bingo = "Sorry, no Bingo."
    end

    puts "The result of your card is: #{bingo}"
end
```

Furthermore, I would write `check_card` like you wrote the rest, it just returns true or false.  Have another function which does the formatting.  Then check_card is easier to read and can be reused.

```
def check_card
    return check_horizontal || check_vertical ||
           check_diagonal_right_to_left || check_diagonal_left_to_right
end

def display_result
    if check_card
        bingo = "BINGO!"
    else
        bingo = "Sorry, no Bingo."
    end

    puts "The result of your card is: #{bingo}"
end
```

Comment: That is a very good point and would ultimately be the direction I'd head, but I was curious as to why I was not able to get the case statement to work. Thank you for reviewing this!

Comment: An alternate syntax for check_card is: `[check_horizontal, check_vertical, check_diagonal_right_to_left, check_diagonal_left_to_right].any?` Probably doesn't really provide an advantage in this case, but would be useful in a case where you wanted to conditionally add checks to the array of 'check' functions

Comment: @FredWillmore Like this?  `def checks [check_this, check_that, check_other] end;  def check_card return checks.any? end`

Comment: @Schwern yes I like your change - the `checks` method could then encapsulate any logic about which things to check - for example if the author later created an option to make the bingo game 3D, they could add a check for matches in the third dimension, and keep the rest of the logic as is: `def checks [check_this, check_that, check_other, (check_3d if 3d?)].compact end`

Answer (score 1):

Later you will find a lot of wonderful methods for making comparisons easy to write and read. What about this?

```
result = "Sorry, no bingo!"
possible_bingos = [
   check_horizontal,
   check_vertical,
   check_diagonal_right_to_left,
   check_diagonal_left_to_right
]
result = "BINGO!" if possible_bingos.any?
```

Also note that you can add more options per line to a case statement line:

```
bingo = case @bingo_card
      when horizontal,vertical then "BINGO!"
      when diagonal_right_to_left,diagonal_left_to_right then "BINGO!"
      else "Sorry, no bingo!"
end
```